# Unable create object of type 'DBContext'. For the different design patterns supported at design time,

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, dbcontext, .net-7.0

While I was adding migration for my DBContext in visual studio with .net 7, I faced this error:

> An error occurred while accessing the Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting services. Continuing without the application service provider. Error: Failed to load configuration from file 'C:\Users\User\VIsualStudioProject\Proj1\Proj1Project\appsettings.Development.json'.
> Unable to create an object of type 'Proj1DBContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728

I wondering how to solve this?

my appsettings.json:

```
"AllowedHosts": "*",
"ConnectionStrings": {
  "Proj1DbConnectionString": "Server=User\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Proj1DbContext;Trusted_Connection=True;TrustServerCertificate=Yes"
}
```

my Program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<Proj1DBContext>(options =>
options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("Proj1DbConnectionString")));
```

my Proj1DBContext.cs:

```
 public class Proj1DBContext : DbContext
 {
  
     public Proj1DBContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
     {
     }

     public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
     public DbSet<Hashtag> Hashtags { get; set; }

 }
```

I had tried to modify my program.cs to this: `builder.Services.AddDbContext<EveryoneShareDBContext>();`

and add a constructor in my dbcontext.cs like this: `public Proj1DBContext(){}`

but then I will faced a new error which said like this:

> No database provider has been configured for this DbContext. A provider can be configured by overriding the 'DbContext.OnConfiguring' method or by using 'AddDbContext' on the application service provider. If 'AddDbContext' is used, then also ensure that your DbContext type accepts a DbContextOptions object in its constructor and passes it to the base constructor for DbContext.

So any help?

Answer (score 0):

You lack of `<Proj1DBContext>` in Proj1DBContext.cs.
Try following.

```
 public class Proj1DBContext : DbContext
 {
  
     public Proj1DBContext(DbContextOptions<Proj1DBContext> options) : base(options)
     {
     }

     public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
     public DbSet<Hashtag> Hashtags { get; set; }

 }
```

Comment: Still the same TT